# Prevent window from being focused when FileChooser is active

Tags: java, javafx, java-8, javafx-8, filechooser

I have a simple JavaFX application, and I am opening a `FileChooser` just by calling `showOpenDialog()`.

I want to disable my main window from being selected while the file chooser is open, and keep it on top of the main window if possible.

Thanks for any help given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the doc of [`showOpenDialog`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/FileChooser.html#showOpenDialog-javafx.stage.Window-) (emphasis mine):

> Shows a new file open dialog. The method doesn't return until the
>   displayed open dialog is dismissed. The return value specifies the
>   file chosen by the user or null if no selection has been made. **If the
>   owner window for the file dialog is set, input to all windows in the
>   dialog's owner chain is blocked while the file dialog is being shown.**

So because of the owner chain, in this case both the `primaryStage` and the `secondStage` are blocked:

```
primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(new VBox(), 300, 300));
primaryStage.show();

Stage secondStage = new Stage();
secondStage.setScene(new Scene(new VBox(), 50, 50));
secondStage.initOwner(primaryStage);

secondStage.show();

FileChooser fc = new FileChooser();
fc.showOpenDialog(secondStage);
```

---

If you modify the last line as

```
fc.showOpenDialog(primaryStage);
```

the `primaryStage` is blocked, but the `secondStage` is available.

---

Finally, if you do not execute this line:

```
secondStage.initOwner(primaryStage);
```

and you call the last line as

```
fc.showOpenDialog(secondStage);
```

the `primaryStage` is not blocked, but the `secondStage` is blocked.

Answer (score 1):

**Before showing the stage**, invoke `stage.initModality` as either `APPLICATION_MODAL` or `WINDOW_MODAL` as appropriate.  Also invoke `stage.initOwner` .

```
Stage stage = new Stage();
stage.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
stage.initOwner(pane.getScene().getWindow());
stage.setScene(new Scene(content));
stage.show();
```

**Note** You cannot apply the above stated rules to `FileChooser`. However, you can use `showOpenDialog(Window ownerWindow)` for it.

```
fileChooser.showOpenDialog(stage)
```

So when you open filechooser.Main window will be blocked.